# error: initializer element is not constant in assigning structure pointers

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gcc

I can successfully compile this c code in one IDE (using c99 compiler) 
but not under linux using gcc

```
#define MAX_STRUCT 3

sstructtype SStructrecord1, SStructrecord2, SStructrecord3;
u32 RecordStructAdd[MAX_STRUCT] = {(u32)&SStructrecord1, (u32)&SStructrecord2, (u32)&SStructrecord3};
```

I have also tried with assigning individual values but still same error.What wrong I am doing here?

```
error: initializer element is not constant
error: (near initialization for ‘RecordStructAdd[0]’)
```

Comment: No, you cannot. As the message already reports: C99 requires `struct` initialisers to be constant.

Comment: So no way to fix it for Linux-gcc?

Comment: Sure: use constant initialisers or normal assignment. Note that you invoke undefined behaviour on 64 bit platforms when casting a pointer to a 32 bit integer and back and then dereference the pointer (any reason why you use jhomebre types anyway? - You use C99, so why not use `stdint.h`?). In general, it is a bad idea to have such unsafe casts.

Comment: Are you showing the code that yielded the error? I see no `SStructrecord1[0]` in your code. Variables addresses are constants, but what's `SStructrecord1[0]`?

Comment: I don't see what is not constant in the initializer. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: You probably meant to use `uintptr_t` instead of `u32` (whatever that is).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I attempted a brief explanation in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33934246/3386109). A full explanation is rather too broad for SO, since it involves the compiler, linker, loader, and executable formats, as well as information about the `sizeof` various types used by a given implementation.

Comment: @ user3386109, your answer makes it clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the cast. If you simply store the pointers as pointers then the compiler won't complain:

```
#define MAX_STRUCT 3

sstructtype SStructrecord1, SStructrecord2, SStructrecord3;
sstructtype *RecordStructAdd[MAX_STRUCT] = {&SStructrecord1, &SStructrecord2, &SStructrecord3};
```

Here's a brief explanation:

The compiler generates an executable that contains relocatable code. The addresses in the executable are placeholders that must be fixed up by the loader at runtime. To help the loader do it's job, the executable contains a [relocation table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)#Relocation_table) which specifies which placeholder addresses must be replaced by which actual addresses when the executable is loaded.

So if you store the address of an object in a static variable, then the executable will have an entry in the relocation table that allows the loader to put the correct address in the static variable at load time.

But if an address is 64-bits, and a `U32` is 32-bits, then casting the pointer to a `U32` only stores a portion of the address, not the full address. The relocation table has no mechanism to fix up partial addresses. Hence, a pointer that you cast to a smaller type is not a compile time constant.

---

Here's what the C specification has to say in §6.6 paragraph 7:

> **6.6 Constant expressions**
>
> ...
>
> 7 More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers.
>   Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the
>   following:
>
> - an arithmetic constant expression,
> - a null pointer constant,
> - an address constant, or
> - an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an    integer constant expression.

An address cast to a `U32` is not one of the allowed constant expressions. But an implementation where a pointer and a `U32` are the same size may let you get away with it.